# TypeError when using gulp to serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-connect

I'm getting the below error when requesting Gulp to serve static content and load the webserver. I'm following the professional angularJS book.
both the package.json and the gulpfile reside in the same folder.

```
[21:30:44] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/pro-angular2/gulpfile.js
[21:30:44] Starting 'connect'...
[21:30:44] 'connect' errored after 96 ms
[21:30:44] TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/kj/Desktop/pro-angular2/gulpfile.js:17:18)
    at module.exports (/home/kj/Desktop/pro-angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/kj/Desktop/pro-angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/home/kj/Desktop/pro-angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/home/kj/Desktop/pro-angular2/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

below is my Gulp code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('default',[],function(){

});

gulp.task('connect', function() {
  var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
  var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
  var connect = require('connect');
  var app = connect()
    .use(require('connect-livereload')({
      port: 35729
    }))
    .use(connect.serveStatic('app'))
    .use(connect.serveIndex('app'));
  require('http').createServer(app)
    .listen(9000)
    .on('listening', function() {
      console.log('Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000');
    });
});
```

and my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "pro-angular2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.4.0",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.4",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.3",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.1.0",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.3.0",
    "opn": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

This is the tree view

```
.
|-- app
|   |-- app.js
|   |-- bower_components
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- main.css
|   `-- main.less
|-- bower.json
|-- gruntfile.js
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- node_modules
|   |-- connect
|   |-- connect-livereload
|   |-- grunt
|   |-- grunt-contrib-connect
|   |-- grunt-contrib-jshint
|   |-- grunt-contrib-less
|   |-- grunt-contrib-watch
|   |-- gulp
|   |-- gulp-jshint
|   |-- gulp-less
|   |-- gulp-livereload
|   |-- gulp-load-plugins
|   |-- jshint
|   |-- load-grunt-tasks
|   |-- opn
|   |-- serve-index
|   `-- serve-static
`-- package.json
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using connect instead of just something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)? It looks like all you're doing is just serving the `app` dir as a static site.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use http-server since i've just started to learn server side javascript ... the above code was actually in a tutorial i'm following... do you have any good resources which i can read?

Comment: Not something that would go with what the tutorial you're doing right now. I'd recommend http-server or live-server, and an npmscript, so `npm install http-server --save` (or live-server) and then in the package.json "scripts" section, `"run": "http-server -p 9000 ./app". No need for gulp here. However, that is drastically different from the tutorial you're running through.

Comment: @Kunkka - Looks like `connect` does not have a method `serveStatic`. Did you try `app.use(serveStatic('./app'))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server-static` and `serve-index` are not part of `connect` anymore. They were extracted as separate modules. You have these separate modules included, so just use:

```
.use(serveStatic('app'))
.use(serveIndex('app'));
```